# Can't get skspritenodes from .sks file to .swift file?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to spawn a player that is added in the GameScene.sks file to my GameScene.swift file and than display this player on the screen. It always give me an error.

Code GameScene.swift file:

```
    let player = self.childNode(withName: "player") as! SKSpriteNode
    player.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
```

Code GameViewController.swift file:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure the view.
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false

    // Create and configure the scene.
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

    // Present the scene.
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

(The player in the GameScene.sks is a Color Sprite with the name player).

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: try to change the name from `"player"` to `"//player"`

Comment: Still doesn't work, but thanks for answering!